# How to simulate `maxdepth` option of find command of linux to python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want a standard python solution for `maxdepth` option in linux. I can simulate the `find` command with `os.walk()` but I want to restrict the depth from code level. I don't want to use `subprocess` or `Popen` in my code.

Comment: I've never heard of a `maxdepth` command in Linux. Do you mean the `-maxdepth` option of the `find` command?

Comment: @MarceloCantos yes that it is. If you want you can edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: it's your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all paths recursively until a certain depth is reached. This solution is not particularly efficient, but it should get you started (Python 3.3 or later required):

```
def find(path, maxdepth=-1, depth=0):
    path = "%s/" % path if path[-1] != "/" else path
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        p = "%s%s" % (path, f)
        yield p
        try:
            if (depth < maxdepth or maxdepth == -1) and os.path.isdir(p):
                yield from find(p, maxdepth, depth + 1)
        except OSError:
            pass
```

Usage:

```
find(path, maxdepth)
# maxdepth=-1 means infinite depth (default)
```